# How can I create a variable group, update the value in a pipeline, and query the value?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

As an end goal I am trying to create an Azure DevOps Dashboard widget that has a table with the project name, the environments (dev, test, prod), and the current version of that project.

I was thinking about creating a variable group in a project called version, with variables such as: `dev = 0.0.0, test = 0.0.0, prod = 0.0.0`

Then I would need to called these variables within my pipeline to update the value, i.e. `dev = 0.0.1`.

After the variable gets updated, I want to query my variable group and display the results in the Query Results extension.

Is this even possible or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I create a variable group, update the value in a pipeline, and query the value?

You could use the REST API or CLI command to achieve this:

For CLI, you could use the command:

```
az pipelines variable-group variable create

az pipelines variable-group variable update

az pipelines variable-group variable list
```

You could refer [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/pipelines/variable-group/variable?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-azure-devops-az-pipelines-variable-group-variable-update) for some more details.

Besides, you could also use the REST API:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

The REST API document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/add?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

Comment: After the variable group is created, and once I use the REST API, is there are way to show that data on the Azure DevOps Dashboard in any way?

Comment: @agw2021, if possible, please check this thread: https://vinijmoura.medium.com/how-to-create-variable-groups-libraries-dashboard-on-azure-devops-4d73ca0529f2